# cloudkit sync with local database

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, cloudkit

I save quite a bit of data to a mysql database on the phone, then upload when we have wifi. I am syncing about 6 tables and have it working properly, need to add more error checking, but it is working with some wait statements thrown in where I need them.

The problem is I am doing each update separately with a request and when the request comes back I don't have the information that I need to delete that entry from the local database, so that it doesn't re-upload duplicate information. Is there a way to save a variable to each upload so that when it comes back I can delete that entry? I can do that with one variable. It tells me the record I updated, but they are all referenced items to the owner and I can't find the info I need. I will be doing about 100 uploads at a time.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem very clearly, but the sort of solutions that come to mind while reading it are KVO or key value observing. Subscriptions also come to mind, although they may be too slow. Using operation blocks is also a possibility, running polling method in the background. Talking polling, delegates comes to mind.

Comment: What I need is a round trip variable, but not storing it in my table. If I send 40 requests to update a table they may or may not come back in the same order that I sent them? So when they come back I need to know which request updated successfully so I can delete that entry from my database. I may have 2 that failed for some reason, and I know that I have to re-submit them. I can do that by sending the ID from the table, when it comes back, I delete that item.

Comment: Grumpy, what a name. Each record in your ckdatabase has a record ID, if you can store the record ID in the MySQL database your be in business. Do so and also set up a subscription that fires every time a record in your ckdatabase gets updated. All you need to do than is match the records updated with the notifications? Does that make sense?